# Securing requests between Android and MVC.Net Core 3 web app

Tags: android, security, model-view-controller, .net-core

I have created an MVC web app using Dot Net Core 3.1 and I have also made an Android app which communicates to the web app using JsonObjectRequests.

Everything works and all is good :-)

Now this is where my knowledge breaks down; How can I make the data sent to and from the MVC and Android apps secure?

Comment: Transfer your data over `HTTPS`.

Comment: i think your question is a bit too broad for stack overflow, it might be better to do some research on security and then asking here for help with more specific implementations. this comment is just as a guide, if you don't find the answer you're looking for

Comment: Do you want to make the _data_ secure as you wrote in the question, or are you aiming to secure the application (frontend and backend) as a whole, or do you have some other goal? Also what do you want to secure it _against_, eg. somebody being man-in-the-middle, a random attacker on the internet, the user itself, something else? In the current form the question is too broad, you should consider all of the above, and in addition to that operations, potentially processes, the SDLC itself and so on. Security is not like you add a few lines of code and it's secure by magic.